# How to plot a chart on Windows Form in real time?

Tags: c#, charts

I want to be able to plot a chart in Windows Form in real time using Microphone input. How would I plot points on a chart whilst constantly refreshing them?

Something like this is the end goal:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q9cRZuosrOs

Comment: This is an *exact* example of what you are trying to do and it looks like a toutorial. With teh Sorucecode being right on GitHub: https://github.com/swharden/Csharp-Data-Visualization/tree/master/projects/18-09-19_microphone_FFT_revisited  So I am unsure about your question.

Comment: I would guess the big issues is getting a sample/redraw rate that WindowsForms Drawcode can sustain. Plus propably seperating out the sampling of the audio into it's own task or even Thread. But it is possible to just rate limit that drawing and the sampling to a maximum.

Comment: @Christopher Unfortunately I can't find the code for the graphs, that only explains how to do a FFT on realtime data. It's the realtime displaying on the chart that I am struggling with.

Comment: It seems clear that https://github.com/swharden/Csharp-Data-Visualization/blob/master/projects/18-09-19_microphone_FFT_revisited/ScottPlotMicrophoneFFT/ScottPlot-2018-09-09/ScottPlotUC.cs is the User part of the Control, https://github.com/swharden/Csharp-Data-Visualization/blob/master/projects/18-09-19_microphone_FFT_revisited/ScottPlotMicrophoneFFT/ScottPlot-2018-09-09/ScottPlotUC.Designer.cs the Designer part. | Basic partial classes of Windows Forms. | He oddly uses quite a lot of nested classes, wich I do not see that often.